# If I have multiple values in a column, how can I count it in SQL?

Tags: sql

Let me illustrate this:

| Student_ID | Course |
| --- | --- |
| StudentID1 | CourseA |
| StudentID2 | CourseB |
| StudentID3 | CourseA CourseB |

There is an existing table that has data that looks like the one above (Not exactly Student & Course, this is more for illustration purpose) and my job is to do a count of how many students for each course. The table is very huge and I do not know how many and what are the courses are out there (Easily in thousands), so wonder if there is a way I can get a list of all these courses and their counts through SQL?

The current method that my team did is SELECT DISTINCT COURSE, COUNT(STUDENT_ID) FROM TABLE GROUP BY COURSE, but this does not work because it treats "CourseA CourseB" as its own.

There are some other columns in this table that I might need to do a SUM as well.

Appreciate any advice on this, thanks!

Comment: You can't sum a *string*. Storing multiple values in a string is a major antipattern and will only cause you problem after problem. Each value should be a row in a normalised table.

Comment: Agree with @Stu, and also, in order to explode your values to multiple rows, check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows). Once obtained the exploded table, you can `group by Course`, and then `count(Student_ID)`

Comment: Some questions: Which DB type are you using? Is there always a space between the courses? It will be possible to do such a select, but I agree that if possible you should go another way.

Comment: Bad design to have multiple courses the way you do.  Better to have table that has per-student/course that one student, multiple values in one column.  Easier for joins later too.

Answer (score 0):

you could use below to find number of students for each course:

```
select course, count(*) as no_of_students
from table 
group by course;
```